# how to size cell in gridview

Tags: iphone, swift, layout, autolayout

I have a gridlist that looks like this

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

private var collection: ACollection?
private var collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout?


override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionViewLayout?.itemSize.width = 128
    collectionViewLayout?.itemSize.height = 227
    view = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout!)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let someObj: SomeObj = collection!.getObject(index: indexPath.item)
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(UICollectionViewCell.self), for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let cellView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: object.image)

    cellView.frame = cell.bounds
    cell.contentView.addSubview(cellView)
    return cell
}
```

I would like my cells to have different aspect ratios though depending on a value in someObj. How can I resize the cells without them overlapping? I have tried to make

```
cellView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:300)
cellView.frame =cell.bounds
```

but the cells overlap.

Comment: I believe you should implement `collectionView(, layout: sizeForItemAt:)` function in the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, since it looks like you are using the flow layout.

Comment: @sCha That works somewhat. What I see is that when I change the size it draws a cell with the old size then another on top with the new size

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'll elaborate a little more about the problem.

First, if you implement `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` method, you don't need to specify the following:

```
collectionViewLayout?.itemSize.width = 128
collectionViewLayout?.itemSize.height = 227
```

which is a default size for every cell.

Second, overlaps you see on top of every default cell are probably the `cellView`s (`UIImageView`s) that you are adding on reused cells. The problem is, you're trying to add `UIImageView` on the current cell every single time delegate asks for the cell. You'll need to check if the `UIImageView` is already there, since the entire cell may have been reused still having the image view which added previously.

Comment: @user2175783 either you add a tag to the view and reference it with `viewWithTag` method or you can define a custom cell and use it so that it comes with all the subviews you need. I personally recommend the second option, but the first option is much easier way to go.